# Setting Events for similar fields in HTML using JQuery, and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core, bootstrap-5

I am not really good at the HTML world, and I'm not even sure how to debug this one. Anyway, I have an ASP.NET core App. My issue is in a CSHTML view. It is a timeclock system. User logs time against an existing job.

I have an Index.cshtml that is working. It will verify a JobNumber to make sure it exists in the database. And if the user enters a partial number and hits F3, it pops up a modal window (I'm using Bootstrap 5) to allow them to select from a list.

The problem is, the user wants to add more Job numbers. So, they can clock time against up to five Jobs at once. So, I am creating new fields, and naming them JobNumber2, JobNumber3, etc.

What I want to do is reuse the existing scripts to add the verification and popup functionality to each of the new fields.

I have tried several different things based on a half a dozen tutorials out there, but I am just not good enough at Javascript and JQuery to know how to do this.

Any help is appreciated!

[EDIT]
Ruikai Feng's answer shows how to match the first function, but that one calls                 validateJobNumber(jobNumber), and the result will update a field -- again based on the same pattern. So, now it updates: jobNumberValidationMessage -- but I need it to update the correct jobNumberValidationMessage depending on which JobNumber field got matched in the first half of this. IDK, maybe these could be combined into one function? I'm not sure. But how do I take what I matched with id^='JobNumber to figure out which jobNumberValidationMessage to update (ie jobNumberValidationMessage2, jobNumberValidationMessage3, etc)  ;

------------ END EDIT

Here's the code I have that is working, but needs changed:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions
@model dynamic

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
                <!-- Clock-In Header -->
                <h3>
                    <img class="logo large" src="logo-png-transparent.png")"
                         alt="Logo" width="100" height="100">  Add Job Number(s) to Track Time for: @Model.Employee.Name
                </h3>
                <hr />  <!-- Ruler Line for Separation -->
                <!-- End Clock-In Header -->
            <!-- Clock-In Form -->
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1 col-md-12 offset-md-0">
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
             <form asp-action="ClockInBegin" method="post">
            <label for="JobNumber" class="col-7 col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Job Number</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" id="JobNumber" name="JobNumber" class="form-control" onkeydown="jobNumberKeyDown(this)" onblur="jobNumberBlur(this)" value="@Model.TrackingItem.JobNumber">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <span id="jobNumberValidationMessage"></span>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="form-check  form-switch col-4 align-with-label">
            <input class="form-check-input"  type="checkbox" value="" id="MultipleCheck">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="MultipleCheck">Multiple</label>
          </div>
         </div> <!-- End form-group row -->
          <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Start Clock</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Clock-In Modal Pop-up -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Select Job Number</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <select id="jobNumberSelect" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select Job Number</option>
        <!-- Dynamic options generated via JavaScript or ajax -->
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">          
            <button type="button" id="CANCEL"class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" id="OK" class="btn btn-primary"   data-bs-dismiss="modal">OK</button>                
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Clock-In Modal Pop-up -->
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#JobNumber").blur(function () {
            var jobNumber = $(this).val();
            validateJobNumber(jobNumber);
        });
        $("#JobNumber").keydown(function (event) {
            if (event.key === "F3") {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (event.target.value.length >= 2) {
                    // Open the modal
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    // Populate the select options
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetJobNumbers")",
                        data: { searchTerm: event.target.value },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#jobNumberSelect").empty();

                            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                                $("#jobNumberSelect").append("<option value='" + item + "'>" + item + "</option>");
                            });
                            $("#jobNumberSelect").val("..."); // clear the initial value. Make them select it
                            //set prompt in first cell of select
                            $("#jobNumberSelect").prepend("<option value=''>Select Job Number</option>");
                            $("#myModal").modal("show");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        $("#jobNumberSelect").change(function () {
            $("#JobNumber").val($(this).val());
        });
        $("#OK").click(function () {
            $("#JobNumber").val($("#jobNumberSelect").val());
            validateJobNumber(); // call the validation
            $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        });

        $('#MultipleCheck').change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).val(true);
                $('[name="MultipleCheck"]:hidden').val(true);
                $("#hiddenFields").show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).val(false);
                $("#hiddenFields").hide();
            }
        })

    });  // end Document.Ready functions

    function validateJobNumber() {
        var jobNumber = $("#JobNumber").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("VerifyJobNumber")",
            data: { jobNumber: jobNumber },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (respdata) {
                // alert(respdata);
                const obj = JSON.parse(respdata);
                var rmessage = obj.message;
                $("#jobNumberValidationMessage").text(rmessage);
                $("#jobNumberValidationMessage").css("color", "green");
            }
        });
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have mutipule inputs like:

```
<input type="text" id="JobNumber1" name="JobNumber1" class="form-control"  value="1">
<input type="text" id="JobNumber2" name="JobNumber2" class="form-control"  value="2">
<input type="text" id="JobNumber3" name="JobNumber3" class="form-control"  value="3">
```

and you want validate the value on blur ,just try as below:

```
$("[id^='JobNumber']").blur(function(e)        
{             
var jobnumber=$(this).val();             
$.ajax({               
 type: "POST",               
 url: "@Url.Action("VerifyJobNumber")",               
 data: { "jobNumber": jobnumber },               
 dataType: "text",                
success: function (respdata) {                     
alert(respdata);                                  
 }            
});        
});
```

With a controller :

```
[HttpPost]       
public IActionResult VerifyJobNumber(string jobNumber)        
{            
  return Ok(jobNumber);        
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: what does id^= mean? I haven't seen that used before

Comment: It's a jqury selector ,it would select All elements with id attribute value starting with "JobNumber",check this document :https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: I've updated what i've tried, if it has  difference between what you excepted,please  point it out

Comment: Sorry, I was stuck on something else. What you gave me works for the first half, but there is a second, and I am not sure how to handle that. I have updated my question, if you could please look at that?

Comment: You could try to add the validated number to cookie if you validate them seperatly,or you want validate all the jobnumber one time ?